# is this efficient way to get data from a database?

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, database

I am developing this iPhone application for a friend and I have to get a lot of data from a MySQL database.

I will be using PHP to get data from the database and then echoing out the data in an organized manner (as XML) and then the iPhone will parse the data into an array through NSXMLParser.

I still haven't tried this yet but just wanted to know how efficient this way is. Will it be sort of slow to do that way and is there any other better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I strongly recommend JSON over XML.

Comment: well could be JSON too I guess

Comment: without knowing what you are doing with this data, this is much like asking "I'm going to do some DIY, is this the right hammer?"

Comment: the data will be shown in tableview!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're focused on efficiency, you want to push work to the fastest/cheapest link in the chain.

The less work the client has to do (which is usually very slow compared to servers) the better.

The less work your database has to do (which is usually very expensive) the better.

So, processing as much as possible in the php layer is the way to go.

Also, constructing your queries so that they are efficient and return the minimal amount of data is also good.

Unless the iPhone actually needs the xml data, don't give it to the iPhone, it will take a long time to download and then more time to parse.

Answer (score 1):

handling and - especially - sending large amounts of data over the Net is always slow.
any chance you can send not "a lot of data" but just amount required at the time?

Answer (score 0):

**Whether it will be slow depends on a number of criteria:**

- The amount of data
- Speed of the network
- The amount of processing to be done on the data by the iPhone app

**Your question is vague. There's no way of knowing exactly what your requirements are.
However, these following points should apply:**

- Only serve the amount of data that you need to send
- Never resend data - if it's new data, cache it. If it's older data, send update tags and check whether it's been updated since.
- Do as much processing on the server as you can - using the iPhone's CPU for processing the data will use a lot more battery than just waiting to receive data from a server.

Comment: I also recommend JSON where possible. I believe (though don't quote me) that parsing it is usually a touch faster. At the very least there is less cruft so a JSON document should be a bit faster to transfer than an XML one.